Is there a performance penalty when using EnumerateFiles() vs. GetFiles() when copying a file each iteration?
Sure there are other ways to do this but just for argument's sake, if I replace EnumerateFiles() with GetFiles() in the code below, there seems to be a performance uptick using the GetFiles(), it is > 1 sec. faster than EnumerateFiles() for 10 directories each containing 10 files.
Does anybody know why that is?
It is interesting because I was under the assumption EnumerateFiles() is more efficient due to the lazy loading and GetFiles() is the old style way of doing things.
Microsoft only says EnumerateFiles() is more efficient when dealing with large collections, nothing about any performance penalties...
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratedirectories?view=net-8.0
Is this because instead of the file system entries are still being enumerated while the file copy action tries to read and write to the disk at different places? So disk head has to switch back and forth? Seems to be something to be aware about!
Follow up question: how would this hold up over a network share?
using System;
using System.IO;    

// Copy all the files in source paths to target paths
foreach( string newPath in Directory.EnumerateFiles( masterRecordingsDirectory, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories ) )                                      
{     
    File.Copy( newPath, newPath.Replace( masterRecordingsDirectory, currentRecordingsDirectory ) );    
}

Edit:
As people in the comments pointed out, both methods call InternalEnumeratePaths() under the hood. The point is though, Get methods then first cast to List before returning, while Enumerate starts yielding up paths while others are still being retrieved. So in my opinion the question still stands, which method would be appropriate for which circumstances? The Microsoft documentation does not go into this much detail.
Edit2: I tested again with differently named files/folders to prevent the caching throwing out the results. I still found a difference in favour of GetFiles()/GetDirectories() (although in the order of ms now).
There are also more file reads for the Enumerate (in the 80's) instead of the GetFiles (in the 50's) which seem to support these results.
But please go ahead and shoot holes in it!
Here is my test code:
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string baseDir = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDocuments), "Test2");
        string sourceDir = Path.Combine(baseDir, "Source2");
        string targetDir = Path.Combine(baseDir, "Target2");


        Directory.CreateDirectory(baseDir);
        Directory.CreateDirectory(sourceDir);
        Directory.CreateDirectory(targetDir);

        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(sourceDir, "Blah2" + i.ToString()));
        }

        foreach (var dir in Directory.GetDirectories(sourceDir))
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
            {
                File.Create(Path.Combine(dir, "Blah2" + i.ToString()));
            }
        }
        // Copy all the files in source paths to target paths
        foreach (string newPath in Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            File.Copy(newPath, newPath.Replace(sourceDir, targetDir));

    }
}


For only 100 files, I would have expected the time to be hugely dominated by copying the files, not enumerating them. Bear in mind that the OS caches file access, so you need to be careful here: whatever you ran second is probably going to be faster than whatever you ran first. I would expect the time difference for EnumerateFiles v GetFiles to be utterly insignificant in comparison.

get files is only one os call and enumerate files is many

It appears that they are aliases of the same method in .NET 8 (Directory.InternalEnumeratePaths). The only difference is that GetFiles consumes the whole enumerator immediately into a List<string> which it then converts to a string[] whether as EnumerateFiles gives you the enumerator to yield on your own discretion instead. It shouldn't affect the speed of a copy operation but it could in some unusual circumstance if the enumerator is running an 'OpenFile' query that locks the file before you do your copy operation which GetFiles would be unaffected by.

ref GetFiles, ref EnumerateFiles

Are the source and destination folders overlapping? Is one contained inside the other?

@canton7 that's a good point actually, the caching could have been what throws it off. Still don't understand why MS keeps the Get methods in addition to the Enumerate if Enumerate is so much more efficient.

@Charlieface No there are no overlaps in the source and destination folders. canton7 raised a good point, I will test again making sure caching is not the issue.

@Prime, indeed under the hood they both call InternalEnumeratePaths but the casting to List and array is the point, this means the operation halts until all paths are indeed enumerated in case of GetFiles(), whereas in EnumerateFiles() operation can continue on already enumerated paths while other paths are being retrieved, right? So disk head has to switch back and forth?

MS is not going to remove those Get methods because of backwards compatibility. Unless your $MFT (NTFS file table) is very large, or it's a networks share, then it will be in memory anyway, so there shouldn't be any disk access for the EnumerateFiles. And on modern SSDs there is much less penalty for random access as there are no moving parts. Use BenchmarkDotNet if you want accurate benchmarking, not a roll-your-own.

@Charlieface I used the PerformanceProfiler in VisualStudio 2022, is that not trustworthy? I have an SSD. And I still don't have an answer to the question, would those disk reads be a problem. My real world problem does involve iterating and copying many small files so it is not a hypothetical problem but one I really would like an in depth answer to. If it was only for backwards compatibility MS would mark then deprecated, right? There may be a reason they don't

No that only measures a single run. BenchmarkDotNet does proper benchmarking: multiple runs, warmup runs, release builds etc. Without a result from a proper benchmarking tool we don't even know if this is a real issue.

I also don't know whether it is a real issue, that is why I am asking the question. I still think the question is legit. Thanks for your input though @Charlieface

So, I used BenchmarkDotNet as suggested by @Charlieface to get more precise test results, and I must concede EnumerateFiles() is the clear winner, being more than 10x faster for local calls. For result over the network the difference seemed even bigger but I was not able to conduct a good test because it ran too long so the test suite stopped half way through with an error.
The results for local file operations:
Job=MediumRun  Toolchain=InProcessNoEmitToolchain  IterationCount=15
LaunchCount=1  WarmupCount=10



Method
Mean
Error
StdDev
Median




Enumerate
46.63 ms
8.663 ms
7.234 ms
43.00 ms


Get
607.26 ms
435.252 ms
407.135 ms
366.41 ms



Disclaimer: I closed all other windows and processes but it may still be the test was not perfect, StdDev on the Get operation was quite high. Although I ran the test multiple times and the results were always similar to the above.
Conclusion as far as I can see: use EnumerateFiles/Dirs instead of Get!
